# Android: Installing Crashlytics in an SDK and its embracing app

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, sdk, crashlytics

I'm developing an Andriod SDK project, intended to be imported by other applications.

Currently I have [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) integrated in my SDK. The problem is that some of our clients who want to use the SDK already have Crashlytics integrated, which causes a conflicts between the two fabric libraries.

Is there a way to have Crashlytics installed in an SDK and in its embracing app?

Comment: Hey Adam, Mike from Crashlytics here.

Awesome question and currently including Crashlytics in your SDK and third party apps is not supported.