# Crashlytics from SDK

Tags: android, ios, error-handling, crashlytics, google-fabric

We are currently building a native iOS and Android SDKs which will be embedded within client apps.

We are using Fabric and Crashlytics but running into issues using Crashlytics to capture errors when running within an SDK. This is due to Crashlytics and related error logging frameworks being initialised globally on app launch which makes it difficult to configure and use multiple instances.

Have read [Android: Installing Crashlytics in an SDK and its embracing app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444744/android-installing-crashlytics-in-an-sdk-and-its-embracing-app) from several years back and doesn't sound promising.

Has anyone had experience doing this with Crashlytics or know of any other better suited solutions?

Comment: Great question! Is the bundle ID of the app static or does it change based on where the SDK is embedded? It seems like this is the case and why you are running into the issue. Each bundle ID must be onboarded separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up going with Sentry as this provided a more lightweight/custom implementation for our SDKs.